# Determining offsetX of a mouseEvent from a particular element with overflow-x: auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, mouseevent

I have an element with overflow-x: auto, and I want to be able to click inside this element and determine the left offset (in px) from the left edge of the element. The issue is that this element contains some other elements within it, so I can't just use the raw offsetX property on MouseEvent, as if I ever accidentally click inside one of the nested divs, it will give me the offset from the left padding edge of that inner div, not the element I want to be targeted.

Additionally, I can't just use MouseEvent.clientX - element.offsetLeft, as if I am scrolled into the element at all, it won't return the value that accounts for the now-hidden scrolled-past part of my element.

How can I either:
1 - Determine the distance between the X pos of the mouse event and the left padding edge of my element?

OR

2 - create a workaround to somehow specify the target of the mouseEvent (this is a read-only property, so I'm unsure if this is even possible)?

I am using Typescript and Angular4, and I dob't want to use jQuery, so please don't suggest a jQuery based solution.  Thanks!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
This can also be done by using the HTML DOM property scrollLeft on the container element

---

Figured out a solution.

We can make sure to only perform mouse movement logic when the offsetX property is with regard to our container element by adding a conditional like so:

```
if (mouseMoveEvent.clientX - myElement.offsetLeft) <= mouseMoveEvent.offsetX) {
    // Handle mousemove
}
else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

In the case of this overflow-x:auto element, mouseMoveEvent.offsetX should only ever be greater than or equal to (mouseMoveEvent.clientX - this.element.offsetLeft).

Therefore, if it isn't, that means our mouseMoveEvent.offsetX property is targeting an inner element, and we can just skip the logic in that case.